# Просмотр пароля элемента input с типом password

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим, у нас есть форма, и в ней есть текстовое поле с вводом пароля:

```
<input id="pass" type="password" name="password" />

var pass = document.querySelector('#pass').value;
console.log(pass);
```

Таким методом можно вывести значение, которое записано в `<input>`.

Мой вопрос:

Мне кажется, **это не безопасно**, может, всем производителям браузеров скрывать это значение?
А при передаче методом POST в форме брать значение из ОЗУ, как вы считаете?

Comment: А вы думаете "document.querySelector('#pass').value" откуда берет значение, если не из ОЗУ?

Comment: Из ОЗУ, но мне кажется лучше не выводить это значение пользователю. А только при отправке формы

Comment: Аргументируйте почему?

Comment: Что если злоумышленник встроит свой js-скрипт на сайт и будет отслеживать нажатие каждой клавиши в поле и отправлять на свой сервер эти значения?

Comment: Если злоумышленник встроит свой js на сайт, то он сможет узнать пароль и без вашего участия

Comment: Нет не узнает! Пароли в БД хранятся в хэше

Comment: @t3mnikov если он встроил JS, то он получит доступ к БД или файловой системе. А значит он получит доступ к скрипту, который этот самый хеш генерирует. Ему уже не обязательно считывать данные с клиента, когда он может их забирать прямо на сервере. И поверьте, в этом случае `type="password"` будет вашей меньшей проблемой. Не забывайте, что браузерами занимается не один человек в подвале, а целое общество профессионалов и если они что-то простейшее не делают, на это есть веские причины.

Comment: Почему не безопасно-то? Пользователь сам ввёл — пользователь сам прочитал своё же значение. Если этот код может выполнить кто-то другой помимо самого пользователя, то у вас большие проблемы, которые никак не связаны с input password

Comment: @t3mnikov если кому-то удалось встроить свой JS в сайт, то что мешает злоумышленнику подписаться на события ввода с клавиатуры сделать кейлоггер? Т.е получается, что если атака произошла, то уже ничего не спасет.

Answer (score 5):

```
<input type="password">
```

придуман не для технической безопасности, а для сокрытия символов от чужих глаз только на мониторе.

Comment: Как минимум пользователь еще не может руками скопировать введенное значение)

Comment: @yolosora при физическом доступе это не проблема. `F12` - console, `document.querySelector('input[type=password]').setAttribute('type', 'text')`

Answer (score 0):

Это было бы хорошо, если бы он, к примеру, шифровался сразу,  но как-бы смысла в этом нет, так как в  браузере есть еще много мест на JS.

Когда ты можешь перехватить пароль например `onkeyup` и т.п.

Поэтому эти  поля предназначены только  для того, чтоб тот кто возле вас, не видел ваш пароль, или например вы показываете демо экрана  и т.п.
Мое мнение, что это так.

Answer (score 0):

Об этом стоит беспокоиться в последнюю очередь. Всё, что может быть украдено с данного поля на вашем сайте, вряд ли будет совершено по вашей вине.
Исключением могут стать подгружаемые скрипты с рекламой, которые часто вызывают сомнения в безопасности у веб-разработчиков.
Шифровать на стороне клиента в realtime дело сомнительное и даже бессмысленное (можно будет ваши алгоритмы подвергнуть реверс инжинирингу).

Answer (score 0):

Есть скрипт, закрывающий лазейки для считывания паролей из полей ввода, а именно чтение атрибута value, смену атрибута type, доступ к паролю через FormData и считывание нажатий клавиш через клавиатурные события.
Ссылка на скрипт:
https://greasyfork.org/ru/scripts/384164-httponly-password-protection
Скрипт можно использовать как user script или вставить на свой сайт на страницу с формами для паролей.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]